# Remove the Dots for Spaces in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I know this has been asked many times on here as I have read so many posts on how to fix this issue... the problem is that CTRL+R CTRL+W (or CTRL+E CTRL+S) doesn't fix it; neither does the menu option to toggle 'View White Space' (Edit > Advanced).  None of the solutions that I can find have fixed this problem.

These dots only appear in the front of a line, and only seem to span across the first two tab/indentation indicators.

I can't figure out how to remove these dots!!  Please help.

[image: Menu]
[image: Problem]

Comment: Not sure what they are, but they're not whitespaces as you would only see a single dot vertically in the middle of the line for each space, or an arrow looking thing for a tab. And they would be shown for every space.

Comment: That's what I as thinking (that they aren't white space).  At this point, they are a huge annoyance!